# Buffering and Subsetting with ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, buffer, error-000229

[image]I am trying to create a tool using ModelBuilder that takes a table of XY data, creates buffers of 1 mile and 0.5 miles around a polygon, selects the XY data that is inside the mile buffer, and copy's the features to a new feature class.

I know I have the correct workflow set up, but when I run the tool I keep getting an error at the Select By Location tool. I'm using the default geodatabase while I'm testing this out. I've tried writing to just a regular folder as well with no dice.

Ultimately my final layers will need to show the half-mile buffer, the mile buffer, and the subset wells.

"ERROR 000229: Cannot open C:*****\ArcGIS\Default1.gdb\CopyFeatures3
Failed to execute (Select Layer By Location)."

It would save me a ton of time if I could get this to work.

Link to the picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/06t35zpdck56qmw/Untitled.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Please use the Picture button to include your picture within your question.

Comment: imgur will not let me add it

Comment: I see - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291672/215590 - make sure you switch it when you can because I know that I am one potential answerer who will not visit dropboxes for pictures, data or code.

Comment: Try inserting a Make Feature Layer between Copy Features (2) and Select Layer by Location

Comment: Select Layer By Location expects layers as inputs and it looks like you are providing feature classes. Have you tried adding Make Feature Layer tools in between?

Comment: To compliment @PolyGeo's answer this is why you should look at the syntax section of the help file for a tool, this specifies the type of parameter, What is Copy Features creating (Featureclass) and what is select by location tool expecting (FeatureLayer)?  Two very different beasts.

Answer (score 3):

I would try adding [Make Feature Layer](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-feature-layer.htm) prior to Select By Location since the tool expects a feature layer and not a feature class. Or make sure all feature classes are added to the map.

You dont need to buffer the polygons since Select By Location have the parameter Search Distance (unless you in fact want to save the buffered polygons).

Model below worked for me. I use the [For Iterator](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/modelbuilder-toolbox/examples-of-using-iterators-in-modelbuilder.htm#GUID-C0E9F998-C1DE-4D52-9FCE-13543FBC0FCB) to select twice with different search distances and output two feature classes.

[image]